# Outlook - How to get folder name of MailItem in VBA macro

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, macros

I have an outlook VBA macro in which I would like to check that a given MailItem object belongs to a specific outlook folder. Is there any way I can accomplish this? I can use

```
Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox").Folders("FOLDER_NAME")
```

to get the folder I want to check my item is a member of, but I don't know how I can directly compare my MailItem to this object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why this didn't work earlier, but I just tried comparing `objFolder.Folders("Inbox").Folders("FOLDER_NAME")` to `Item.Parent` and now that comparison works, before it was giving me an error, but it works now so this should be resolved.

Here is my macro for anyone that might have this issue in the future:

```
Public Sub Do_Stuff_To_Items(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.GetFirst ' folders of your current account
    Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox").Folders("FOLDER_NAME")
    If Item.Parent = objFolder Then
        ' Do Stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. 
I voted for your post. It is recommended that you can mark it as an answer later.